# About interface and extension

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

Suppose I have an interface `A` with method `a`, and `B` is a concrete class which implements `A`.

```
public interface A {
    public void a();
}

public class B implements A {
    public void a() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Now suppose there is a class `C` which wants to reuse the implementation from class `B`, but it also want to introduce new behavior, so it adds an additional method `c` and also extends class `B`.

```
public class C extends B {
    public void c() {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Now as the type of class `C` is actually `A`, so based on the dependency inversion principle as in the SOLID principle, it seems the following should be used when invoking the method `c` of class `C`. But the call will not be valid as the interface `A` only has method `a`.

```
public class D {
    public void d() {
        A object = new C();
        object.c();  // cannot call as the interface A only has method a
    }
}
```

Am I misunderstanding the dependency inversion principle in SOLID, or what should be the proper class hierarchy in this situation ?

Comment: The first problem is that instantiating `new C()` inside of `D` violates Dependency Inversion, because `C` is a concrete class and dependencies can't point at concrete implementations. That problem has to be solved before any methods like `c()` can be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in your question

> Am I misunderstand the dependency inversion principle in SOLID

I would say you are confusing it with the [Liskov substitution principle](https://stackify.com/solid-design-liskov-substitution-principle/).

I'm certain that your question is a duplicate, but I have no clue how to search for them. When someone finds a duplicate, I will delete this answer.

From the code in your question:

```java
A object = new C();
```

The "type" of variable `object` is `A`. Hence it only has access to the methods and members of class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time the method public void c() is not visible to the object of type A, thats why you will get compile time error. To use this you need to add abstract method inside the interface A.
Your interface should looks like :

```
public interface A {
    public void a();
    public void c();
}
```

As your class B is also implementing the interface A, now you can do one of the following:

1. make class B abstract
2. implement the method public void c() inside class B

Now the following code will execute the method public void c() of class C.

```
A object = new C();
object.c(); // call method from class C
```